# Impala select * does not show all details of table

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I have an sql query within impala `select * from table`  but when I execute this certain columns are missing .

Whereas when I do  `describe table`  those columns are there.

I cannot show the snippet but the types not showing up are **maps**,**arrays**, and **structs**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impala doesn't support that. Complex types have to be unpacked to be displayed.

> The result set of an Impala query always contains all scalar types;
>   the elements and fields within any complex type queries must be
>   "unpacked" using join queries. A query cannot directly retrieve the
>   entire value for a complex type column. Impala returns an error in
>   this case. Queries using SELECT * are allowed for tables with complex
>   types, but the columns with complex types are skipped.

Source: [Queries and Complex Types](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_complex_types.html#complex_types_queries)