# How to unpack complex column in Impala Hadoop?

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I have a table which has a colums 
`a:Int`
`b:array<struct<c:int, d:int>>`

I cannot view the complex column b when I `select *`. 
What query should I use to unpack it using join?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Impala select \* does not show all details of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623711/impala-select-does-not-show-all-details-of-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select a, b.c, b.d from table,table.b`